# jquery radio onclick has been triggered many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let e = $('#test')
e[0].onclick = () => {
  console.log('triggered!')
}
e.click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="radio" onclick="foo()" />button
```

If I use $.click(),the radio will be triggered three times

It will work normally if I just click the button or use triggerHandler() to trigger it.I tried to let it return a false value or trigger it by trigger('click'),but none of them work.It will still be triggered three times.I have no idea why it acts like that.

Comment: The example above only triggers once for me

Comment: Are you using jquery's 3.6.0

Comment: You need to use the `change` event instead

Comment: I opened the question in Chrome and clicked the 'Run code snippet' button above.  There was only one console record.  If you're getting something different then you need to include that code in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Using .on('click', cb) or .click(cb) for short seems to solve that. It seems that mixing more vanilla approach with jQuery causes issues.

```js
let e = $('#test')
e.click(() => {
  console.log('triggered!')
})
e.click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="radio" />button
```

Comment: I know it,because it is triggered by js click method.I'm confused why $.click() will trigger it multiple times.Is it a jquery bug?I found if I switch to lower version of jquery,then the $.click() will trigger it only once

Comment: it may be. And if so I don't understand the down votes on the question.

Comment: Maybe it’s because I didn’t describe my question well at first.This is my first time I have asked programming questions online QAQ